# Cannot get audio to play on React application when run on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My audio plays just fine when I run my application on codesandbox, but now that I've imported my React application locally, I'm encountering this error message every time I trigger the audio play prompt in my program:

`DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.`

My `audio_clips` folder is an immediate subfolder in my `public` folder, which houses my `index.html` file, so I don't *believe* that the url path is the issue. I tried making use of the encodeERIComponent in case the underscore in each of the urls was causing any problems, but that made no difference.

Here is the file where the problem originates:

```
const KEY_TO_CLIP_URL_MAP = {
  Q: "./audio_clips/808sub.wav",
  W: "./audio_clips/iELECTRIBE-kick-10.wav",
  E: "./audio_clips/iELECTRIBE-kick-7.wav",
  A: "./audio_clips/lowerthud.wav",
  S: "./audio_clips/schumacher2.wav",
  D: "./audio_clips/snappy-clappy.wav",
  Z: "./audio_clips/spindown.wav",
  X: "./audio_clips/synth-blobble-zap.wav",
  C: "./audio_clips/whuuup.wav"
};

export function playAudioClip(keyPressed) {
  const audioURL = KEY_TO_CLIP_URL_MAP[keyPressed];
  let audioElement = new Audio(audioURL);
  const audioPromise = audioElement.play();

  if(audioPromise !== undefined) {
    audioPromise.then(() => {

    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(audioURL);
      console.log(audioElement);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to just use the source urls for the audio clips from where I found them on the internet instead of trying to get them to work locally.

Answer (score 0):

try and wrap your paths in require('path_string') and Webpack will resolve those paths for you.